# One-time working timer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer, state

I am feeling myself totally confused, because I still work on this issue from yesterday and nothing help.
So, issue: I have To-Do list. Every task has timer. Only one timer can work at the same time, so user can do only one task at the same time.
I thought that I can do 'Start' buttons at another tasks disabled, when one of timer running, but I supposed that I did mistake in my setState, because all timers are still running together =(
I read documentation but it is not helpful for me.
Also, I have file TodoTextInput, which is generate these tasks and I thought maybe I should paste my timer here, but it is strange.

For full info I leave here two files.
Thank you for any help!

*TodoItem* *(issue here)*

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import classnames from 'classnames'
import TodoTextInput from './TodoTextInput'

export default class TodoItem extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { secondsStart: this.props.minSeconds, timerRunning: false }
  }

    static propTypes = {
    todo: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    deleteTodo: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    completeTodo: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }

  static defaultProps = {
      minSeconds: 0
  }
  handleSave = (id, text) => {
    if (text.length === 0) {
      this.props.deleteTodo(id)
    }
  }

handleStartClick = () => {
    if (!this.state.timerRunning) {
      this.incrementer = setInterval(() => {
        this.setState({
          secondsStart: (this.state.secondsStart + 1)
        });
      }, 1000)
      this.setState({
        timerRunning: true,
        currentTodoId: this.props.todo.id,
        runningTodoId: this.props.todo.id
      });
    }
  }


  getSeconds = () => {
    return ('0' + this.state.secondsStart % 60).slice(-2)
  }

   getMinutes = () => {
    return Math.floor((this.state.secondsStart / 60)%60)
  }
    getHoures = () => {
    return Math.floor((this.state.secondsStart / 3600)%24)
  }


  handleStopClick = () => {
    clearInterval(this.incrementer)
    this.setState({ timerRunning: false, currentTodoId: null, runningTodoId: null });
  }

  render() {
  const { todo, completeTodo, deleteTodo} = this.props

  const element = this.state.todo ? (
      <TodoTextInput text={todo.text}
        onSave={(text) => this.handleSave(todo.id, text)} />
    ) : (
        <div className="view">
          <input className="toggle"
            type="checkbox"
            checked={todo.completed}
            onChange={() => completeTodo(todo.isRequired)} />
          <label>
            {todo.text}
          </label>
          <div className="buttons">
            <h6>{this.getHoures()}:{this.getMinutes()}:{this.getSeconds()}</h6>
            {(this.state.secondsStart === 0)
              ? <button className="timer-start" onClick={this.handleStartClick} disabled={this.state.timerRunning }>Start</button>
              : <button className="timer-stop" onClick={this.handleStopClick} disabled={!this.state.timerRunning && this.state.runningTodoId !== this.state.currentTodoId}>Stop</button>
            }
          </div>
          <button className="destroy"
            onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo.id)} />
        </div>
      )

    return (
      <li className={classnames({
        completed: todo.completed,
      })}>
        {element}
      </li>
    )
  }
}
```

*TodoTextInput* *(just in case)*

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import classnames from 'classnames'

export default class TodoTextInput extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    onSave: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    text: PropTypes.string,
    placeholder: PropTypes.string,
    newTodo: PropTypes.bool
  }

  state = {
    text: this.props.text || ''
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    const text = e.target.value.trim()
    if (e.which === 13) {
      this.props.onSave(text)
      if (this.props.newTodo) {
        this.setState({ text: '' })
      }
    }
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ text: e.target.value })
  }

  handleBlur = e => {
    if (!this.props.newTodo) {
      this.props.onSave(e.target.value)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input className={
        classnames({
          'new-todo': this.props.newTodo
        })}
        type="text"
        placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
        autoFocus="true"
        value={this.state.text}
        onBlur={this.handleBlur}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        onKeyDown={this.handleSubmit} />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: So I understand that the problem is that you want all the timers to be disabled when you start, am I right? Where are you using the TodoItem component?

Comment: Yes, when I click 'Start' at one task - I should have not opportunity to click 'Start' at another tasks. Only when I click 'Stop' at this task I can run another task and timer.
TodoItem component I import in component MainSection - it it the biggest part of app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. You could **store the id of the currently running timer in the state of `MainSection`** and change it from a `TodoItem` with a callback function like `completeTodo`. Then, you can send this attribute of the `MainSection` state to each `TodoItem` as a prop and check in it if it's the one that's running:

```
    render() {
      const { todo, runningTodoId, startTodoTimer, completeTodo, deleteTodo} = this.props
      let disable = runningTodoId == todo.id;
    }
```

The whole point is that you need to communicate to the `MainSection` which `TodoItem` is running or at least if there is a `TodoItem` running. As far as I can see all you are storing about the state of the timer is local to the state of the `TodoItem`, so the other `TodoItems` can't know whether they should be able to start or not.

A TODO list is [almost a classic example of the Redux usage](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html). I don't know if you could introduce Redux into your app but it's definitely a great tool when it comes to storing a global state.

Comment: Yes, I use Redux in my app and I just rewrite "classical example" with my features. 
So anyway I need to communicate with MainSection, I am right?

Comment: Either you comunicate with MainSection or you use the store of Redux. For example, if you store the id of the currently running Item with Redux you wouldn't have to store it in MainSection.